# Unless issue with Puppet

Tags: powershell, puppet

The rest of my Puppet code runs fine. I am able to install printers successfully starting with their drivers in the below portion. What I am running into however is that "unless" is being ignored. Not super familiar with PowerShell in Puppet but maybe someone can spot what I am missing.

```
$printers.each |Integer $index, Hash $printer| {
  exec { "add printer driver ${printer[driver_name]} for ${printer[name]}":
    command  => "Add-PrinterDriver -Name \"${printer[driver_name]}\"",
    unless   => "&  if((Get-PrinterDriver -Name \"${printer[driver_name]}\" - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){exit 1}else{exit 0} }",
    provider => powershell,
```

I have tried with

```
"&  if((Get-PrinterDriver -Name \"${printer[driver_name]}\" - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){exit 1}else{exit 0} }",
```

and `"& { exit ((Get-PrinterDriver -Name \"${printer[driver_name]}\" -ErrorAction Stop) -eq $null) }",`

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when running `--debug` and `--verbose` $null was not finding any sort of value. I needed to escape the `$null` using `\$null` as well as remove the `else {exit 0}`.

New code below.

```
exec { "add printer driver ${printer[driver_name]} for ${printer[name]}":
  command  => "Add-PrinterDriver -Name \"${printer[driver_name]}\"",
  unless   => "if ((Get-PrinterDriver -Name \"${printer[driver_name]}\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq \$null) {exit 1}",
  provider => powershell,
}
```